# CSS 3 slide-in from left transition

Tags: css, css-transitions

Is there a cross-browser solution to produce a slide-in transition with CSS only, no javascript? Below is an example of the HTML content:

```html
<div>
    <img id="slide" src="http://.../img.jpg />
</div>
```

Answer (score 366, accepted):

You can use CSS3 transitions or maybe CSS3 animations to slide in an element.

For browser support: http://caniuse.com/

I made two quick examples just to show you what I mean.

**CSS transition (on hover)**

[Demo One](http://jsfiddle.net/2vLjU/1/)

Relevant Code

```
.wrapper:hover #slide {
    transition: 1s;
    left: 0;
}
```

In this case, I'm just transitioning the position from `left: -100px;` to `0;` with a 1s.  duration. It's also possible to move the element using `transform: translate();`

**CSS animation**

[Demo Two](http://jsfiddle.net/mhRec/2/)

```
#slide {
    position: absolute;
    left: -100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    -webkit-animation: slide 0.5s forwards;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
    animation: slide 0.5s forwards;
    animation-delay: 2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide {
    100% { left: 0; }
}

@keyframes slide {
    100% { left: 0; }
}
```

Same principle as above (Demo One), but the animation starts automatically after 2s, and in this case, I've set `animation-fill-mode` to `forwards`, which will persist the end state, keeping the div visible when the animation ends.

Like I said, two quick examples to show you how it could be done.

***EDIT:***
***For details regarding CSS Animations and Transitions see:***

**Animations**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations

**Transitions**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions

Answer (score 249):

## Use CSS3 2D `transform` to avoid performance issues (mobile)

> A **common pitfall** is to animate `left`/`top`/`right`/`bottom` properties instead of using [css-transform](/questions/tagged/css-transform) to achieve the same effect. For a variety of reasons, the semantics of transforms make them easier to offload, but `left`/`top`/`right`/`bottom` are much more difficult.

Source: [Mozilla Developer Network (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/Performance/Firefox_OS_performance_testing)

---

Demo:

```js
var $slider = document.getElementById('slider');
var $toggle = document.getElementById('toggle');

$toggle.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var isOpen = $slider.classList.contains('slide-in');

    $slider.setAttribute('class', isOpen ? 'slide-out' : 'slide-in');
});
```

```css
#slider {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.slide-in {
    animation: slide-in 0.5s forwards;
    -webkit-animation: slide-in 0.5s forwards;
}

.slide-out {
    animation: slide-out 0.5s forwards;
    -webkit-animation: slide-out 0.5s forwards;
}
    
@keyframes slide-in {
    100% { transform: translateX(0%); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide-in {
    100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(0%); }
}
    
@keyframes slide-out {
    0% { transform: translateX(0%); }
    100% { transform: translateX(-100%); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide-out {
    0% { -webkit-transform: translateX(0%); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
```

```html
<div id="slider" class="slide-in">
    <ul>
        <li>Lorem</li>
        <li>Ipsum</li>
        <li>Dolor</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<button id="toggle" style="position:absolute; top: 120px;">Toggle</button>
```

Comment: that is a great answer but I want it to slide in when user scrolls at this point of the page. What changes would you suggest?

Answer (score 39):

Here is another solution using css transform (for performance purposes on mobiles, see answer of @mate64 ) without having to use animations and keyframes.

I created two versions to slide-in from either side.

```js
$('#toggle').click(function() {
  $('.slide-in').toggleClass('show');
});
```

```css
.slide-in {
  z-index: 10; /* to position it in front of the other content */
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden; /* to prevent scrollbar appearing */
}

.slide-in.from-left {
  left: 0;
}

.slide-in.from-right {
  right: 0;
}

.slide-in-content {
  padding: 5px 20px;
  background: #eee;
  transition: transform .5s ease; /* our nice transition */
}

.slide-in.from-left .slide-in-content {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.slide-in.from-right .slide-in-content {
  transform: translateX(100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
}

.slide-in.show .slide-in-content {
  transform: translateX(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide-in from-left">
  <div class="slide-in-content">
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem</li>
      <li>Ipsum</li>
      <li>Dolor</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="slide-in from-right">
  <div class="slide-in-content">
    <ul>
      <li>One</li>
      <li>Two</li>
      <li>Three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="toggle" style="position:absolute; top: 120px;">Toggle</button>
```

Answer (score 6):

I liked @mate64's answer so I am going to reuse that with slight modifications to create a slide down and up animations below:

```js
var $slider = document.getElementById('slider');
var $toggle = document.getElementById('toggle');

$toggle.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var isOpen = $slider.classList.contains('slide-in');

    $slider.setAttribute('class', isOpen ? 'slide-out' : 'slide-in');
});
```

```css
#slider {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.slide-in {
    animation: slide-in 0.5s forwards;
    -webkit-animation: slide-in 0.5s forwards;
}

.slide-out {
    animation: slide-out 0.5s forwards;
    -webkit-animation: slide-out 0.5s forwards;
}
    
@keyframes slide-in {
    100% { transform: translateY(0%); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide-in {
    100% { -webkit-transform: translateY(0%); }
}
    
@keyframes slide-out {
    0% { transform: translateY(0%); }
    100% { transform: translateY(-100%); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide-out {
    0% { -webkit-transform: translateY(0%); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%); }
}
```

```html
<div id="slider" class="slide-in">
    <ul>
        <li>Lorem</li>
        <li>Ipsum</li>
        <li>Dolor</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<button id="toggle" style="position:absolute; top: 120px;">Toggle</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this for right to left sliding

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a#click-a').click(function() {
    $('.nav').toggleClass('nav-view');
  });
});
```

```css
/*nav*/

.nav {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 70px;
  width: 250px;
  height: calc(100vh - 70px);
  background-color: #333;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.nav-view {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav ul li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.nav ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <a href="#" id="click-a">Toggle</a>
</div>


<div class="nav ">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var $slider = document.getElementById('slider');
var $toggle = document.getElementById('toggle');

$toggle.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var isOpen = $slider.classList.contains('slide-in');

    $slider.setAttribute('class', isOpen ? 'slide-out' : 'slide-in');
});
```

```css
#slider {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.slide-in {
    animation: slide-in 0.5s forwards;
    -webkit-animation: slide-in 0.5s forwards;
}

.slide-out {
    animation: slide-out 0.5s forwards;
    -webkit-animation: slide-out 0.5s forwards;
}
    
@keyframes slide-in {
    100% { transform: translateX(0%); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide-in {
    100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(0%); }
}
    
@keyframes slide-out {
    0% { transform: translateX(0%); }
    100% { transform: translateX(-100%); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide-out {
    0% { -webkit-transform: translateX(0%); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
```

```html
<div id="slider" class="slide-in">
    <ul>
        <li>Lorem</li>
        <li>Ipsum</li>
        <li>Dolor</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<button id="toggle" style="position:absolute; top: 120px;">Toggle</button>
```

```js
var $slider = document.getElementById('slider');
var $toggle = document.getElementById('toggle');

$toggle.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var isOpen = $slider.classList.contains('slide-in');

    $slider.setAttribute('class', isOpen ? 'slide-out' : 'slide-in');
});
```

```css
#slider {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.slide-in {
    animation: slide-in 0.5s forwards;
    -webkit-animation: slide-in 0.5s forwards;
}

.slide-out {
    animation: slide-out 0.5s forwards;
    -webkit-animation: slide-out 0.5s forwards;
}
    
@keyframes slide-in {
    100% { transform: translateY(0%); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide-in {
    100% { -webkit-transform: translateY(0%); }
}
    
@keyframes slide-out {
    0% { transform: translateY(0%); }
    100% { transform: translateY(-100%); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide-out {
    0% { -webkit-transform: translateY(0%); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%); }
}
```

```html
<div id="slider" class="slide-in">
    <ul>
        <li>Lorem</li>
        <li>Ipsum</li>
        <li>Dolor</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<button id="toggle" style="position:absolute; top: 120px;">Toggle</button>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.