# slide bottom border in from left on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have this css for my menu:

```
#menu {
    display:inline;
    float:right;
}
#menu > ul > li {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:20px;
    min-width:70px;
}
#menu > li {
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
#menu > li:hover {
    color:#000000;
}
#menu li a {
    display:block; 
    padding-top:25px;   
    border-top:4px solid #FFFFFF;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align: center;
}
#menu li a:hover { 
    border-color:#000000; 
    color:#000000;
}
```

i want to be able to make a bottom border (like the top one but on the bottom) slide in from the side on link hover

here is a fiddle: *http://jsfiddle.net/2w6NB/*

Answer (score 0):

Position your element you want coming from the left to be

```
left: -200px; //or however much it takes to hide the element completely or partially
```

Then here is some sample code that you might be able to successfully use to model your functionality:

```
$( "#item" ).hover(function() {

        $( "#item" ).stop().animate({
            left: "-1" //shows item
        }, 400);}, function() {


        $( "#item" ).stop().animate({
             left: "-160" //this determines how far back the item goes after hovering 
        }, 400);

});
```

Let me know if you have questions or if it works.

Comment: This assumes the OP is using jquery.

Comment: dont suppose you cud create an example for me?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this link will help you: [Sliding with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16989585/css-3-slide-in-from-left-transition) and [Affect Other Element on Hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-a-div-is-hovered)

The goal here is to slide a line/boarder from an `"overflow:hidden;"` div using either CSS webkit transition or a javascript function. You cannot have this happen on the same object as the menu links, but you can set it so that there is a div directly underneath it that will let the bar slide in.

(An example of this is setting `"right:200px;position:absolute;width:200px;border-top:solid black 5px;"` to the inside object and the div surrounding it to `"overflow:hidden;width:200px;"`. Then you use the transition on a css hover event or a javascript function to move over the object back into the div so that it can display.

I hope that helps!