# How to make a button that slides out and shows the full text onmouseover?

Tags: html, animation, button

So, I see a few things that seem like they might be relevant to this question, but they aren't similar enough for me to be able to use their answer.

Anyway, basically, I want to have a button with a dollar sign in my sidebar.
When the mouse is hovered over it, I want it to smoothly slide out and have the word "Donate" on it, keeping the $ on the right side of the button. Then, when the mouse is no longer hovering over it, I want it to slide back in.

**Example:**

Mouse not over:

**$**

Mouse over:

e **$**

te **$**

(slides all the way out)

Donate **$**

Except with real buttons.
**Note:** If it can't use an image as the button, that's fine. It'd be nice if I could, but honestly it doesn't matter in the long run, as I can probably make the HTML button look just as nice.

This seems like a really simple question, so I really hate to ask about it, but I simply can't figure it out.

**Edit:**

Well, here's one thing I tried.

In head tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
    {
    $("#imgAnimate1").hover(
        function()
        {
            $(this).attr("src", "donateB.gif");
        },
        function()
        {
            $(this).attr("src", "donateA.png");
        });
</script>
```

Where the image is:

```
<div id="sidebar">
<img id="imgAnimate1" src="Images/donateA.png" alt="" >
</div>
```

Result (WHILE hovering mouse over it):
http://prntscr.com/45js7q

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show research effort and previous attempts at solving the problem.

Comment: @esqew and preferably a fiddle =)

Comment: You seem to be rather new to web design. I would highly recommend you start learning CSS if you haven't already. It can solve all your problems. Stack Overflow is not a site where people will provide solutions without some demonstrated effort by the person asking for help.

Comment: CSS3 animations might be what you are looking for I presume? You might want to look into that

Comment: esqew: Alright edited with an example of something I tried.

@Jason I'm not new, I've been messing with HTML for well over a year now, and was in my high school web design class. I just haven't ever looked into more advanced things, I've only gotten really good at the more basic things.

IndieRok: Alright, I'll look into it. :)

Comment: You have syntax errors in your example (unclosed `$(document).ready()` block, unclosed `$.hover()` block). Are you sure that's the code you were using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These resources will get you started in the right direction.

[CSS3 transition 1](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transitions/)

[CSS3 transition 2](http://blog.crazyegg.com/2012/04/23/css3-transition-effects/)

[Stack Overflow post about same kind of question + Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16989585/css-3-slide-in-from-left-transition)

You can achieve this without even using jquery. Only CSS and CSS3 markup

Example:

```
.myImage{
    width:200px;
    height:25px;
    background:#C96666;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    left:-180px;
    transition: 1s;
}

.myImage:hover{
    transition: 1s;
    left: 0;
}
```