# set backgroundPosition and setInterval

Tags: javascript, html

So I made a code

```
function slide()
{
    var x=1;
    while (x<=512) 
    {
        document.getElementById("slide").style.backgroundPosition = x+"px 0px";
        x++;
    }
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xmqkg1jh/)

I want to make a transition from `backgroundPosition - 0` to `backgroundPosition 512`. This code above changes immediately from 0 to 512, I want to make it like 1<100ms break>, 2, 3... 

I tried change `x++` to `setTimeout(function(){x++), 100)` but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Whilst you can indeed do this with `setInterval` in JavaScript, would you alternatively be able to use an answer that uses CSS animations?

Comment: Really, don't do this with JavaScript. Use CSS animations. Have a look at this for inspiration http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16989585/css-3-slide-in-from-left-transition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use setTimeout() and call function :

```
function slide(x) 
{
    if(x==undefined) var x = 1;
    if(x >= 512) return;
    document.getElementById("slide").style.backgroundPosition = x+"px 0px";
    x++;
    setTimeout(function() {
        // recall function and add other code if you want.
        slide(x);
    }, 100);
}
slide();
```

Comment: _Really_ minor nitpick - it should be `if (x > 512)` to match the OP's intent, or better still, do `if (x<=512)` before the call to `setTimeout`, so you save one invocation of the function at the end.