# building a right side menu that sticks on center html

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

First of all I am so sorry that I create this new question, but I have been looking for a while now for this menu/navigation that sticks on the right center of the html page. An example is like the social plugins that you can see floating on the left side of this page: http://www.addthis.com/social-buttons

I want to make a similar with my own images that leads to different html pages. Hope someone can help.

Comment: did you inspect the html document before? That should be the first place to look for if you want to learn how to build it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply this to the container div of the menu:

```
.menu {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: You probably want to add  transform: translateY(-50%)  so that the menu is centered. (note that you need prefix for browser support)

Comment: @TinaFlorijn You're welcome. I also edited the answer because Daniel made a good point. Don't forget to mark it as accepted if it worked for you :)

Comment: i have not enough reputation to thumb up :(

Comment: @TinaFlorijn Oh, that's ok. I meant clicking on the checkbox on my answer, to accept it :)

Comment: yes done thank you! do you also know how to make a div slide into the center html from the right side the page?

Comment: @TinaFlorijn No problem! You mean the div being on the center of the page? And always staying there?

Comment: no i mean like when i click one of this menu items a hidden page must slide from the right into the html till the center of the page. and when you click the  cross X on the corner of this new page this page must go back

Comment: @TinaFlorijn this is a good answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31819499/1815813 Let me know if you need help with it afterwards

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with some CSS3 plain positioning like the axis-translate properties, but I think the better thing to do is trough using [**Flexbox**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Simply create a container around your element and give it the following properties:

```
.container {
    display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: center;
  align-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Your element will be within the `.container` div ofcourse.

This is the prefixed version, it is the reason why this is so long.