# How to Slide an Element Horizontally

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

I need to add a else statement to a click function so the .container disappears when the button is clicked a second time.

```
function() {

    $('div.container').css({'width':'350px'});

    } else {

    $('div.container').css({'width':'0'});

     }

});
```

**Edit:**

I need the element to toggle slide left on a button click.

Comment: Where is `if()`?

Comment: Not sure where to add the if

Comment: use toggleClass() with css to do that.What happen if more than two times same button clicked?

Comment: I want to use .animate({ width: 'toggle'},

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**toggle() Method:**

Using jQuery you can use the [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method.

> The toggle() method toggles between hide() and show() for the selected elements.

So you can simply have

```js
$('#buttonId').on('click', function(){
    $('#container').toggle();
})
```

```css
div{
  background-color: #a8a8ff;
  height: 100px;
  width: 350px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="buttonId">Click Me!</button>
<div id="container" class="long"></div>
```

**toggleClass() Method:**

According to your comment if you want to toggle a style (e.g: width) it's better and cleaner to define a class for your style and use [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) method.

> The toggleClass() method toggles between adding and removing the class.

```js
$('#buttonId').on('click', function(){
    $('#container').toggleClass('long short');
})
```

```css
div{
  background-color: #a8a8ff;
  height: 100px;
}

.long{
  width: 350px;
}

.short{
  width: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="buttonId">Click Me!</button>
<div id="container" class="long"></short>
```

**animate() Method:**

Based on your second commend you can use the [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method to simulate the slide functionality.

> The jQuery animate() method lets you create custom animations.

To slide the element to left: (Credits to [JQGeek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/74285/jqgeek) for his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596608/slide-right-to-left).)

```js
$('#buttonId').on('click', function(){
    $('#container').animate({width:'toggle'},350);
})
```

```css
div{
  background-color: #a8a8ff;
  height: 100px;
  width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="buttonId">Click Me!</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Yes bit how can i toggle the width of the container $('div.container').css({'width':'350px'});

Comment: Yes thanks, but I want it to slide toggle from the left. Can i use this or do i need to use .animate?

Comment: @Dev I updated my answer again. Check it out for slide toggle functionality.

Comment: If i add content to the container, how do i slide that off as well?

Comment: @Dev This isn't actually an slide, it's more of a slide-like effect but we are toggling the `width` attribute. If you want an actual slide (moving the element inside and outside the view) I suggest you take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16989585/css-3-slide-in-from-left-transition) and the first two answers.

Comment: I'm referring to the content inside <div id="container">Slide This Content</div>

Comment: @Dev I know but what I'm saying is that if you just simply have text inside it it will cut and disappear. But if you have something like `padding` attribute or some nested elements, my solution may not behave as expected. So in this case you should take a look at the above link I provided in my previous comment.

Comment: I did look at it but it doesn't provide the solution so the text slides off as well rather than crunch up.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
$(document).on('click', 'button_selector', function () {
    if (true) {
        // your code
    }
    else{
        // your code
    }
});
```

> suggestion

you can use toggle for this

```
$(document).on('click', 'button_selector', function () {
    $('div.container').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Why do i need 'button_selector'

Comment: button which handle the event, you have to give that button selector like  `id, class` or any other selector attribute

Comment: The only problem i have with this is it doesn't toggle sideways

Comment: toggle will toggle your div or say element meaning it will appear or disappear your element like show or hide

Comment: I want a slide toggle from the left Can i use this or do i need to use .animate?

Comment: you need to animate or use a toggleClass for this and make css class if you are using then might use if else in it

Answer (score 0):

You can follow my code

```
$(function(){
   var firstClick = 0;
   $("button").click(function(){
       firstClick++;
       if(firstClick==2)
          $('div.container').hide();
       else
         $('div.container').show();
   });
})
```