# How to make an animation of closing an element from left to right

Tags: jquery, css, animation, less, css-animations

How to make an animation of closing an element from left to right and open from right to left by clicking on the icon?

Using jquery and adding CSS elements to create animations
Or using just CSS | less preprocessor

```html
<form id="search_mini_form" class="navbar-form navbar-right">
    <div class="form-search ajax-search" style="display: flex">
     <div class="ajax-search-form">
         <input type="text" class="" id="search" />
     </div>
      <span>Icon</span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Opening and closing input by element `<span>Icon</span>`

Comment: I think you can do it with just Css

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS 3 slide-in from left transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16989585/css-3-slide-in-from-left-transition)

Comment: There are so many same questions here on SO and examples on internet that you really can do this by yourself. Just google your tittle. Try something and let us know when you get stuck.