# How can I add animation to my burger menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css

While clicking `myLinks` heading should come from left side and push the page with having a transition of 3 seconds. I have tried so many methods still I'm getting wrong.

If anyone could help me it will be welcome.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myLinks");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
}

.topnav #myLinks {
  display: none;
}

.topnav a {
  color: black;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  display: block;
  align-content: center;
  background: #ddd;
}

.topnav a.icon {
  background: white;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

.active {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.topnav-buttons {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 48px;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <a class="active">INVOICE</a>
  <div class="topnav-buttons">
    <button onclick="location.href='invoiceAdd.html'">Add Invoice</button>
  </div>
  <div id="myLinks">
    <a href="transactions.html">Transaction</a>
    <a href="product.html">Product</a>
    <a href="#news">News</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
  </div>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: check it that may be its helpfu. [CSS 3 slide-in from left transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16989585/css-3-slide-in-from-left-transition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transitions cannot be used for the display property so instead you should use opacity. Also, developers usually do not mix CSS code into JS file and vice versa. Instead, you should use the `classList.toggle` property in javascript to switch between states in the classes.

```css
.topnav .my-links {
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
    transition: opacity 200ms ease;
}

.topnav .my-links.show {
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
}
```